# php Simple html dom parser returns always false

Tags: php, html, parsing, web-crawler

hi guys I'm trying to parse some page with simple html Dom parser but it doesn't  works in this site I search some data but I can not understand what is the problem is .

```
<?
include("./simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://ko.pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/%EC%A0%84%EA%B5%AD%EB%8F%84%EA%B0%90');

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) 
   echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

?>

this is my code and is this error because of like header and user agent ?? and then how can I fixit?

Comment: Which lines are successful and which are failing to deliver what is expected?

Comment: at foreach error becomes. i expected to get all pokemon datas.

Comment: And you are saying that the `$html->find('tr')` part works when you build `$html` from other urls?  So what is ko.pokemon's `$html` holding and how does it differ from other sites that work properly?  Do you have errors turned on?  Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Your script does search for  tags and should output the href of these tags. Since href is a html attribute which is applied on  link tags, the script will not output anything.

You should probably rewrite the script like this:

```
<?php
include("./simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://ko.pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/%EC%A0%84%EA%B5%AD%EB%8F%84%EA%B0%90');

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
   echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Or if you want to get the links run it like this:

```
<?php
include("./simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://ko.pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/%EC%A0%84%EA%B5%AD%EB%8F%84%EA%B0%90');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
   echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>
```